# Compare value in ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, contains

I have string

```
String str = "51;60;61;62;63;64;73;75;76;77"
```

and convert str into ArrayList

```
listId = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str .split(";")));
```

i debug and item of listId have enough data but problem happens when :

```
    id = String.valueOf(v.get(i).getCourseId());
    if (!listId.contains(id)) {
      logger.log("List id dont have id:"+id);
    }
```

and result is:

```
List id dont have id: 51
```

i dont know why it dont recognize value 51 is exist in list, i try remove number 51 and set number 60 is first element -> result is:

```
List id dont have id: 60
```

Please help me,show me where wrong and how to solve problem! Thanks :)

Comment: What is the list `v`?  Maybe it doesn't contain 51 or 60?

Comment: print `v.get(i).getCourseId()` and see what it outputs

Comment: If `logger.log("List id dont have id:"+id);` logs `List id dont have id: 51` then there is a whitespace before the `51` in your `id` variable. You should clean the courseId strings. Maybe by using `.trim()`.

Comment: If all the id's are ints, you would make your life easier to store them as ints rather than strings.

Answer (score 2):

You have a leading whitespace. Use `trim` to get rid of it before you compare it e.g.

```
!listId.contains(id.trim())
```

Comment: I _think_ i was a few seconds faster with my comment - but hey, take it! ;)